# Some websites work better with a vpn what could be the cause?

Tags: networking, vpn, isp

I always had problems with services like [twitch](https://www.twitch.tv) and not being able to open some websites unless i spam refresh.

Today i decided to try a vpn ([proton vpn](https://protonvpn.com/)) and all those problems went away, twitch was completely smooth 1080p and all the websites that didn't open unless i spammed refresh worked fine, those sites were [gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/) and [vim fandom wiki](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Vim_Tips_Wiki)

Do you guys that understand a lot about networking know what could cause this, my bet is on my ISP messing with my network packets. I live in Portugal my ISP is meo and i have 200/100Mbps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this could be due to an ISP throttling your bandwidth. Can't think of any other reason you would be seeing increased network performance with a VPN. Your ISP could easily be targeting video streaming traffic and that would explain your issue with Twitch. They call this "congestion-management". While utilizing your VPN the traffic will be encrypted. This will disrupt their throttling capability.